# Mysql php / ajax to more database information

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How do I create the images from MYSQL to be links to the information associated to them on a seperate page?

Here's my code so far after getting the initial database connection:

```
   $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

   for($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
    echo '<img src="' . mysql_result($result, $j,'picture_url') . "class='releasesImage' id='" . mysql_fetch_row($result, $j, 'releases_id') "/>" . "width= "200" height= "200"> ';
```

This will get the images to layout and I'm using the database auto increment as the image ID. How do I perform an Ajax request to use the images id to load more information related to the image.

The request in a seperate division on the same page needs to be something on the lines of

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM releases WHERE id = 'image id'"

    echo '<h2>'                 . mysql_result($result, $j,'track_title')       . '</h2><br />';
    echo '<h3>'                 . mysql_result($result, $j,     'artist')       . '</h3><br />';
    echo 'Remixed by: <ul><li>' . mysql_result($result, $j, 'remix1')       .     '</li>';
    echo '<li>'                 . mysql_result($result, $j, 'remix2')           . '</li>';
    echo '<li>'                 . mysql_result($result, $j,     'remix3')       . '</li></ul><br />';
}
mysql_close($db_server);
?>
```

The goal being that a page full of album covers loaded from a database, once the album cover has been clicked a seperate division will load the album and artist information. Can this be done with a Jquery ajax request?

I've been looking online and I can only find examples using pre wrtten drop downs, not using content already loaded by the same database.

Any help would be massively helpful.

Thanks

Comment: If I understand right, you're storing the *path* of the images and can't show they up?

Comment: Please show us what you have so far. Are you trying to output HTML?

Comment: Many thanks for you trying to help, I've since updated the question with the hope that this makes more sense.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).